# Who can peer review tag wiki entries?

Tags: support, reputation

I created a few tag wikis and they need to be peer reviewed before they are published.

> Note that if you have less than 4000 reputation, your tag wiki will be
>   peer reviewed before it is published.

There is no member of SFSE that has at least 4000 reputation, so how can these get approved?  Is the limit to approve / peer review lower than the 4000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page for reviewing tags is: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits

It seems you need 1500 Reputation to approve the edits:

> This page requires more privileges The page you're trying to visit
>   requires the privilege “approve tag wiki edits.”
>
> You receive additional privileges on Salesforce by earning more
>   reputation through participation on the site. When you have earned at
>   least 1500 reputation, you will receive the “approve tag wiki edits”
>   privilege and will be allowed to view this page.
>
> Visit the privileges page to learn more about the privileges you can
>   earn.

Comment: There is also a differance between a beta site and a released one.

Beta sites need less rep.

Comment: That will be something worth keeping in mind when we end up making the transition as that could make some people lose permissions they were use to

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, users on the SE Meta with enough rep, can also review and approve edits.

i.e.

https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/geoff-dalgas